# CSS Keyframe animation overlapping

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a 4x4 table that lights up in a color sequence. There are a total of 5 colors and these light up in sequence in different table columns and rows. I managed to get one color going but when I try to add another Keyframe animation it changes both of the cells to the new color? Any help would be much appreciated. The code below is only showing one color.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<center><h1>Light Sequence</h1></center>
<table>
<table style="background-color: #5D5D5D;" table align="center"
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="d"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td class="a"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="c"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="b"></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td class="e"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
td { width:400px; height:200px; border:2px solid #333; }
td.a { background-color:#5D5D5D; }
td.b { background-color:#5D5D5D; }
td.c { background-color:#5D5D5D; }
td.d { background-color:#5D5D5D; }
td.e { background-color:#5D5D5D; }
.a {
height:200px;
width: 400px;
border: 2px solid #333;
-webkit-animation: animate_bg 3s;
animation: animate_bg 3s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
```

}

```
@keyframes animate_bg {  
0%   {background-color:#5D5D5D;}  
100% {background-color:yellow;}
```

}

```
@keyframes animate_bg {
0%   {background-color:#5D5D5D;}
100% {background-color:yellow;}
```

}

```
@-webkit-keyframes animate_bg {
0%   {background-color:#5D5D5D;}
100% {background-color:yellow;}
```

}

Comment: you have incorrect HTML at the start of your table.

Comment: can you be more clear about what you are wanting? Is it a random square, and each successive square will light up with the next colour?

Comment: The first square should light up a certain color then should turn off and then the next square should light up and so on, so its in a light sequence

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is to change the name of the keyframe for every cell. Each keyframe should have a **unique** name if it is doing a different action.

For Example:

CSS:

```
td { width:400px; height:200px; border:2px solid #333; }
td.a { background-color:#5D5D5D; }
td.b { background-color:#000000; }
td.c { background-color:#ffffff; }
td.d { background-color:#414141; }
td.e { background-color:#383838; }
.a {
height:200px;
width: 400px;
border: 2px solid #333;
-webkit-animation: animate_bg 3s;
animation: animate_bg 3s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.b {
height:200px;
width: 400px;
border: 2px solid #333;
-webkit-animation: animate_bg2 3s;
animation: animate_bg2 3s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes animate_bg {  
0%   {background-color:#5D5D5D;}  
100% {background-color:yellow;}  
}

@keyframes animate_bg {
0%   {background-color:#5D5D5D;}
100% {background-color:yellow;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes animate_bg {
0%   {background-color:#5D5D5D;}
100% {background-color:yellow;}
}

@keyframes animate_bg2 {  
0%   {background-color:#000000;}  
100% {background-color:red;}  
}

@keyframes animate_bg2 {
0%   {background-color:#000000;}
100% {background-color:red;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes animate_bg2 {
0%   {background-color:#000000;}
100% {background-color:red;}
}
```

See the edit [Live](http://jsfiddle.net/1or2hc0k/).

Comment: Do you know a way to make it so the first square to turns off then the second turns on and so on?

Comment: Yes of course, you will just have to add animation-delay in every keyframe, so that the first one will be delayed 0 seconds and the second one will be delayed 5 seconds for example, so the sequence will be 0,5,10,15 etc.. that means the delay between animation and the other is 5 seconds.